# Possible bug in Badge Progress Window? (wrong next step)

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

In my Badge Progress window I can see I edited 73 posts and it says the next step will be 500, to reach "Copy Editor" badge, bypassing the actual next step that is "Strunk & White", reached after 80 post edits.

I wonder if it's a bug or a desired behaviour? The other progress bars seem to indicate the next step, not the last one.

[image]

Comment: This is desired behaviour.

Comment: @Martijn, could you provide an explanation of why?

Comment: Why the other shows the next step then? It is incoherent, in my modest opinio.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: all three badges below that line are fixed. Why would Civic Duty remain unchanged after you reach it, but the badge underneath that one switch from Strunk & White to Copy Editor?

Comment: @Martijn, because Civic Duty is the last (and first) badge of its kind (total number of votes). On the other hand, Strunk and White is "on the way" to Copy Editor.

Comment: @AndreaCarrer: Only the first badge, for reviewing, shows progress to two different goals. The other 3 are shared among the various queues as well, which is also 'inconsistent'. But as a group, they *are* consistent.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: again, that would make that section of the UI inconsistent, creating an expectation that there is a gold badge following *Civic Duty*.

Comment: @Martijn, IMHO the inconsistency is already there: review badges do go from Custodian to Reviewer to Steward. (*Edit: not sure about Custodian, as I already have all five of them so I cannot test.*)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Custodian is also shown.